# Convert the data frame having month, year and count columns to time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame with columns `month, year, count`.

[image: dataset]

Now how can I convert this data frame to time series(from `data frame` class to `ts` class). So that final output should be like this

[image].

> The above image shows the `AirPassengers` R built in data set. I want
>   to convert my table in to the same format.

I tried to use answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996756/convert-data-frame-to-time-series-in-r) question. But I didn't get the proper answer. I also tried to use aggregate functions but I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please share the code you're working on so others can help

Comment: Its a data frame and I want to do a time series analysis. In order to do that I need to convert the 'data frame' to 'ts' format. Here I am stuck and I don't know how to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data are not equally spaced in time moreover it is not sorted and possibly repeating you should aggregate the data, make a dummy `data.frame` with equally spaced year-month data. Then `merge` it with initial `data.frame` and, finally, transform to `ts`. Please see the code below:

```
library(lubridate)

# simulation data frame
set.seed(123)
n <- 50
df <- data.frame(
  month = sample(month.name, n, replace = TRUE),
  year = sample(2010:2018, n, replace = TRUE),
  count = 100 * abs(rnorm(n))
)
head(df)
#      month year      count
# 1    April 2010  25.331851
# 2  October 2013   2.854676
# 3      May 2017   4.287046
# 4 November 2011 136.860228
# 5 December 2015  22.577099
# 6  January 2011 151.647060


# transformation to ts-object
df$ymd <- ymd(paste0(df$year, " ", df$month, " ", "1")) # transform to year-month-date format
df3 <- aggregate(count ~ ymd, df, sum ) # aggregate by monthly count


df2 <- data.frame(ymd = seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2015-01-01"), by = "months")) # convert to data.frame

df_r <- merge(df2, df3,  all.x = TRUE) # merge data.frames (left join)
df_r$count <- ifelse(is.na(df_r$count), 0, df_r$count) # substitute NA's to 0's
ts_r <- ts(df_r$count, freq = 12, start = c(2010, 1), end = c(2018, 12)) # transform to ts
print(ts_r, digits = 3)
```

Output:

```
         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2010  22.049   0.000   0.000  25.332   0.000 203.493   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000  70.920
2011 151.647 173.265 114.881   0.000   0.000   0.000 154.875   0.000 102.557   0.000 136.860   0.000
2012   0.000 136.065   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000 101.858   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.576
2013   0.000   0.000   0.000  18.130  23.873  54.772  28.477   0.000  70.387   2.855   0.000 205.008
2014   0.000   0.000   0.000  23.570   0.000   0.000   0.000  68.801   0.000   0.000 132.995   0.000
2015   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000 117.630   0.000   0.000 122.072 230.917   0.000   0.000  60.541
2016   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000 100.574   0.000   0.000 146.093   0.000
2017   5.300 107.179 263.554 124.820   4.287   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000  64.438   0.000   0.000
2018   0.000   0.000  43.518   0.000   0.000   0.000  12.385   0.000   0.000 109.684   0.000   0.000
```

Comment: Than you @Artem. Even my data also having some NA values. I want to apply ARIMA model and want to forecast for the next 2 months. Does these NA values trouble me to do that?

Comment: @Techie VISH, it's a problem, but you can cope with it somehow w/ [imputeTS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf), package.

Comment: This solution did not work for me.  For `df2 <- data.frame(ymd=as_date(x))` it returned the error message: `Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”`

Comment: @jua-kali, OK, updated. (either `lubridate` package was updated or R itself).